# Spring Webflow and JQuery

Tags: jquery, spring-webflow

I am now working in a Spring project using the Spring webflow.
The JavaScript library I would like to use JQuery.
How to integrate JQuery project in Spring and Spring webflow?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, it is simply a matter of copying the JQuery lib into your war directory. That will make the file accessible from your Website (i.e. you are going to server it from your Java app server). You can then refer to it from your Web pages.

Comment: Hi,
I will make in a Web page
Users specify a multiple private vehicles data and address data and then save the specified data into database.
The whole thing is to be realized with JQuery.
Does JQuery library a method that can do that easily?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the quickest way to start using it is to provide a link to the Google repository for jQuery in a script tag in the jsp or HTML page you want to use it.

**E.g.:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I used the following tutorial to get started :

http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-mvc-3-and-jquery-integration.html